# Formatting Excel Row Space Javascript ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, activexobject

How do I fix the row spacing on my excel activexobject spreadsheet. The rows are too small for all of the information to display in the worksheet. Any other references for activexobject excel spreadsheets would be appreciated too.

```
$scope.exportStudents = function () {
    excel = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');
    excel.Workbooks.Add();
    excel.Application.Visible = true;
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "User ID";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Name";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Emergency Phone";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Cell Phone";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Provider";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Emergency Phone";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 7).Value = "E-Mail";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 8).Value = "Hire Date";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 9).Value = "Grad Date";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value = "Major 1";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 11).Value = "Major 2";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 12).Value = "School";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 13).Value = "Active";
    excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 14).Value = "Admin Status";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
excel.ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

Docs: [Object model reference (Excel 2013 developer reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194068.aspx)

Its also fairly simple to translate a recorded macros VBA to JScript.